# How do I call database insert operation using ants golang

Tags: go, memory-management, concurrency, goroutine, pool

I  have a for loop, which inserts data into the 2 different tables. How can I use ants(below package) in this case.

GH Package Ref: https://github.com/panjf2000/ants

```golang
for _, row := range rows {
  user := User{}
  user.Name = row.Name
  user.Email = row.Email
  err := dm.Insert(&user)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  address := Address{}
  address.Address1 = row.Address1
  address.Address2 = row.Address2
  address.PinCode = row.PinCode
  address.City = row.City
  err := dm.Insert(&address)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```golang
func insertRow() {
    // TODO add code to get 'rows'

    const workerCount = 10
    p, err := NewPool(workerCount)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer p.Release()

    rowChan := make(chan RowType)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    insertRecords := func() {
        defer wg.Done()
   
        row <- rowChan

        user := User{}
        user.Name = row.Name
        user.Email = row.Email
        err := dm.Insert(&user)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        
        address := Address{}
        address.Address1 = row.Address1
        address.Address2 = row.Address2
        address.PinCode = row.PinCode
        address.City = row.City
        err := dm.Insert(&address)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }

    for _, row := range rows {
        wg.Add(1)
        _ = ants.Submit(insertRecords)
        rowChan <- row
    }

    wg.Wait()
}
```